# Does there exist a material through which light can only pass alog one axis?

Tags: optics, visible-light, glass

What I mean is that if I put a block of this "magic glass" onto the tip a flashlight I would not see any light unless I look through the glass at just the right angle.
For example, it seems like a material composed of many microscopic aligned optical fibers might behave like this.
However, I also feel like this might count as passively colliminating light "too easily" in the sense that laws about entropy etc. make it impossible.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: would this be what you are looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolator_(microwave) ?

Comment: From what I can tell this device permits transmittion in one direction along a certain axis, but blocks it in the other direction. I am looking for a material which has a certain axis through which light can travel (in both direction). An example would be quite simply a tube. But I am looking for someting more homogeneous, a material with a tubular microstructure that makes it transparent when looking "throgh the tubes", but opaque when not.

Comment: How about macroscopically aligned toilet paper tubes?